# Network connection issue

Tags: networking, digital-ocean

We have a linux machine on Digital Ocean and tomcat is running overthere. We want to connect remote MSSQL server Database (which is on our local windows machine) but it's not connecting.

We tried ping command and telnet command on port 1433 as well..nothing is connecting to my windows machine.

Please let me know what we are missing or what do we need to configure.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure your local machine as a server, accessible from the internet.  But you will need to provide protection for your database server.

Comment: Thanks for reply... as i am newbie to networking so please guide me what step is needed to configure my local machine as a server.

Comment: Please don't go that way then, even an experienced administrator will have a hell of a job securing this.  Better add a database server (eg. MariaDB) to your cloud, and export the data you need from your MSSQL to the MariaDB.